# Flow does not registed selection of picklist in flow when run as site guest user in embedded service

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, external-services, embedded-services

I inserted an embedded service deployment into an external site that launches a flow. I have a picklist field that my "support Site Guest User" cannot seem to fill in for the flow.

[image]

Here is the Edit Screen for the specific screen. As you can see this is the standard picklist component and I have manually set the options to select.

[image]

When I run the debug flow in Salesforce, the picklist actually registers that I have selected a choice. As soon as I run this embedded screen flow on my external site, the flow does not recognize that I have selected an option. What is interesting is that the text area field beside it works perfectly. I have went into Profile of the guest user and made sure that this user can access create and read on the case object and can access and edit all fields on the case object. I also ensure that my flow runs in system context without sharing-Access all data.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the section to divide the two components. This is blocking the flow from recognizing the value is being selected in the picklist. Probably an SFDC bug.